# Convert english Date with parse exact

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I try to convert a english date to an german, but my format is not good.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime currentCultureDate = DateTime.Now;
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

Console.WriteLine("Format: " + format);
Console.WriteLine("Original Date: " + currentCultureDate);

DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currentCultureDate.ToString(), format, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));

Console.WriteLine("Converted Date: " + convertedDate);
```

FormatException.....

Comment: You're using `ParseExact` which in your case expects the format `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"`, but you're using it on `currentCultureDate.ToString()` which is not in that format, hence a `FormatException`.

Comment: but i converted it with toString(), so its no datetime anymore and in the right format

Comment: Not true. Print `currentCultureDate.ToString()` and look at the format. It's separated by `/`. You specify a format with `.` hence the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)  is used to create a `DateTime` from a `string`. You can pass a `DateTimeFormat` or `CultureInfo` which will be used to convert that string to `DateTime`.

The method *does not* convert it to a `string` in another `CultureInfo`, say `de-DE`. Therefore you can use [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string germanFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing what you say: Your code actually tries to **parse** the date in *German* format:

```
// This is German format
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

// This takes a date and parses it using the ABOVE FORMAT - which is German
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currentCultureDate.ToString(), format, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

If you already have a `DateTime` you want to **output** in German format, you don't need `ParseExact`, but `ToString`:

```
string german = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

A `DateTime` itself doesn't have any culture formatting attached. It is just a date and a time. Only when you *output* a `DateTime`, it somehow needs to be converted into a string and to do so, culture information is required. So the rule of thumb is:

1. If you get a string that represents a date and time value, you need to **parse** it into a `DateTime`, either using a fixed format and `ParseExact` or relying on the framework, passing the source culture information to `Parse` or `TryParse`.
2. If you have a `DateTime` and want to **output** it, you need to format it using `ToString`, providing either a fixed format string and culture information, or use `ToString` only for the current thread's culture.